# Authenticate with passport on external API server

Tags: passport.js

I want to have a secure api server in the cloud. It contains all the passport code and routes for login, register, logout, etc. The problem is that I want to call this API from an external client via an http client such as $http or 'request'.

Are there any examples of someone doing passport authentication using external APIs? What about my case where the only thing I introduced was an HTTP client.

I tried setting it up locally with an Http client calling localhost and it didn't work.

This is the login api that I would like to eventually move to the cloud and access with an http client over the web.

```
app.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res) {
console.log("external Login API: " + req.user.email)
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    console.log("In Login. Apparently authenticated")
}
res.send(JSON.stringify(req.user))
});
```

This is the local route that calls the function that calls the external api.

```
app.post('/app/login', publicLoginApi.login);
```

Here is the code that calls the external login api

```
exports.login = function(req,res){
    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/login', //URL to hit
        qs: {from: 'Web App', time: +new Date()}, //Query string data
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        body: JSON.stringify({email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password})
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log("login request failed");
        } else {
            var user = JSON.parse(response.body)
            if(req.isAuthenticated()){
                console.log("Authentication working");
            }
            console.log("login request success");
            console.log("Success user email: " + user.email)
            //console.log(body)
            //console.log(response.body.email)
            return res.send(200,user)
        }
    });
    }
```

Don't forget this is all still local. If I directly call the /api/login function from my HTML view everything works well. But if I call /app/login to simulate an external call to /api/login over http, req.isAuthenticated is false by the time /api/login calls back to the callback behind the /app/login route. As you can see, I test isAuthenticated in the third block of code in this post. It fails there. Is it because this is not a valid express middleware pattern(err,req,res,next) and therefore fails to pass stuff?

It would be nice if someone could offer advice on the endgame solution of external api server and also a solution for my current local testing problem involving the http clients.